For a lie algebra, why is $\lambda(h_\alpha) = \langle \lambda, \alpha^\lor \rangle$?
Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie algebra, $K$ be the killing form of the Lie algebra, and define $t_\alpha \in \mathfrak{t}$ (the maximal torus) by $K(t_{\lambda}, x) = \lambda(x) \quad \forall x \in \mathfrak{t}$ (and then define $h_\alpha = \frac{2}{K(t_\alpha, t_\alpha)}t_\alpha$). Then, define $(\lambda, \mu) := K(t_\lambda, t_\mu)$, and $\alpha^{\lor}(\lambda) = \frac{2(\alpha, \lambda)}{(\alpha, \alpha)}$.
I don't know if this is a dumb question, but why is $\lambda(h_\alpha) = \langle \lambda, \alpha^\lor \rangle$? My lecturer is taking it for granted, but I'm not really sure why it's true.

Using your notations we have that:
$$\begin{aligned}\lambda(h_\alpha)&=\frac{2\lambda(t_\alpha)}{\alpha(t_\alpha)} \\ &= \frac{2K(t_\lambda,t_\alpha)}{K(t_\alpha,t_\alpha)}\\ &= \frac{2(\lambda,\alpha)}{(\alpha,\alpha)}\\ &= \langle \lambda, \alpha^\vee \rangle.\end{aligned}$$
Note that the last equality holds because trace forms (and hence the Killing form, which is the trace form attached to the adjoint representation) are symmetric, and so $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is symmetric, too.

Thanks so much! This was so small but was killing me!
